# Represening audio .wav file numerically

Tags: java, audio, representation, wav

I am currently doing a project which captures sound and I am recording it in `.wav` file format, but further I have to process the sound by applying various formulas and hence it needs to be represented in numerical format.

Currently I am using following attributes while recording the sound:

```
AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
String encString = "linear";
float rate = 44100;
int sampleSize = 16;
String signedString = "signed";
boolean bigEndian = true;
int channels = 2;
```

The above code is written for Java.

Comment: Needs clarification. Technically, as the sound is a WAV it is already being "represented in a numerical format". That's what "digital audio" means. So...what attributes of the sound do you need to represent? Pitch Frequency? Volume? Tempo?  The more specific your question the more specific and constructive we can be in answering it.

Answer (score 0):

im working on a similar project. when you go to write the data chunk, do:
`Console.writeLine(whatever_array_youre_storing_the_data_in[i]);`
and your console with give you all the values from -32767 to 32767 you've used in said array
for me, i just saved the shorts directly as i wrote them, so for me it was
`writer.Write(short.Parse(random.Next(-32767,32767).toString());`
but to get then numeric data in int16 i would set the random number to a short, before writing it to console. hope this answered your question! it was kinda vague!

lastly, if you have enough time, you can always use a hex-editor!

//please note this is both pseudo code and an implementation of c#, idk much about java, other than that it was superclose to actionscript in syntax